# Turn Android Facebook request into AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-asynctask

I'm trying to implement some Facebook API sample code into my app and I'm getting an error that I've learned is because I'm trying to make requests from a UI and that I need to do them from an AsyncTask. I've looked at the documentation but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

Here is the error I'm getting: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)

Here is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);     
    this.buttonRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRequest);
    this.buttonRequest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickRequest();
        }
    });
    this.editRequests = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRequests);
    this.textViewResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResults);

    this.session = createSession();
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (this.session.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data) &&
            pendingRequest &&
            this.session.getState().isOpened()) {
        sendRequests();
    }
}

private void onClickRequest() {

    if (this.session.isOpened()) {
        sendRequests();
    } else {
        StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback() {
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (exception != null) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(GraphApiSampleActivity.this)
                            .setTitle(R.string.login_failed_dialog_title)
                            .setMessage(exception.getMessage())
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null)
                            .show();
                    GraphApiSampleActivity.this.session = createSession();
                }
            }
        };
        pendingRequest = true;
        this.session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
    }
}

private void sendRequests() {
    textViewResults.setText("");

    String requestIdsText = editRequests.getText().toString();
    String[] requestIds = requestIdsText.split(",");

    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
    for (final String requestId : requestIds) {
        requests.add(new Request(session, requestId, null, null, new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                String s = textViewResults.getText().toString();
                if (graphObject != null) {
                    if (graphObject.getProperty("id") != null) {
                        s = s + String.format("%s: %s\n", graphObject.getProperty("id"), graphObject.getProperty(
                                "name"));
                    } else {
                        s = s + String.format("%s: <no such id>\n", requestId);
                    }
                } else if (error != null) {
                    s = s + String.format("Error: %s", error.getErrorMessage());
                }
                textViewResults.setText(s);
            }
        }));
    }
    pendingRequest = false;
    Request.executeBatchAndWait(requests);
}

private Session createSession() {
    Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        activeSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(appId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
    }
    return activeSession;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
Request.executeBatchAndWait(requests);
```

do:

```
Request.executeBatchAsync(requests);
```